# Making bibtex reference entry bold?

Tags: bibtex, bold

How do I make some reference entries bold in bibtex?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on the bibliography style you're using. But you could use the common commands to choose bold typeface: `\textbf` and `\bfseries` work in BibTeX entries as well.

For instance, with this file `tex.bib`

```
@book{texbook,
author = {D.E. Knuth},
title = {\textbf{The {\TeX}book}},
publisher = {Addison Wesley},
year = 1986
}
```

and that simple example

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*{\refname}{{\TeX} books}
\begin{document}
\nocite{texbook}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{tex}
\end{document}
```

you would get:

[image]

The bold typeface has been added to the italic shape of the plain style. It's just an example, I would not combine font properties this way.

A more consistent way would be to modify the bibliography style according to your needs. Or use biblatex.

Comment: Note that your Bibtex file assumes you are using Latex if you follow this advice, which is not a big assumption, but some people use Bibtex with Context and even a few with Plain Tex.