# Elegant way to make entire citation bold

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bold, ieeetran

Is it possible to make an entire reference appear bold in the references section when using BibTeX? I'm using the [IEEE templates and `.bst`.](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/authors_journals.html#sect2)

I found [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/making-bibtex-reference-entry-bold), but is there a more elegant way to highlight certain entries rather than just adding `\textbf{}` to every field in my `.bib` file?

Note that I only want to highlight selected entries from my bilbiography, so changing the whole thing wouldn't accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Unfortunately, I can't use biblatex as `\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}` differs from what I get using the official IEEE `.bst`

Comment: Nope, it's completely arbitrary in that sense. I'm trying to highlight certain references for someone else to look at.

Comment: I think you can simple setup `biblatex` but you can't simple setup the bst -- method. So it's easier if you try `biblatex`.

Comment: @user825518 I'd love to know what is wrong with the `biblatex` IEEE style: please report the issues to joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming numeric citations, here's a way: put the following code in your document preamble.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_boldcite_list_clist
\cs_new:Npn \boldcite_checkkey:n #1
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_boldcite_list_clist { #1 } { \bfseries } { \mdseries } \boldcite_bibitem:n {#1}
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \boldcite_bibitem:n \bibitem

\RenewDocumentCommand{\bibitem}{m}
 {
  \boldcite_checkkey:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\boldreferences}{m}
 {
  \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_boldcite_list_clist { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

You can then add any number of commands

```
\boldreferences{key1,key2}
```

where you list the keys of the references you want to embolden.

Comment: I apologize for my delay in response, but thank you very much! That does exactly what I was looking for!