# IEEETran bibtex with titles in bold

Tags: bibtex, formatting

This is what a normal reference using IEEETran.bst looks like:

[1]
J. Bardeen, L. N. Cooper et al., “Theory of superconductivity,”
*Physical Review*, vol. 108, no. 5, pp. 1175–1204, Dec. 1957.

This is what I would like to get (notice the title in bold):

[1]
J. Bardeen, L. N. Cooper et al., “**Theory of superconductivity**,”
*Physical Review*, vol. 108, no. 5, pp. 1175–1204, Dec. 1957.

This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53983/bold-of-authors-list-changes-style-with-bibtex) outlines how to do this very efficiently using build-in commands from the IEEETran.bst style. I however can't find how to do something similar for the title. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, there is no way to do this using the BSTcontrol functions.
As a workaround, I modified the IEEETran.bst template as follows:

1. Add the following function:

   `FUNCTION {bold}
   { duplicate$ empty$
       { pop$ "" }
       { "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
     if$
   }`
2. Find the following function: `FUNCTION {format.article.title}`
3. Add the word `bold` right under `select.language`. The result should look something like this:

   ``` FUNCTION {format.article.title}
   { title duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   { this.to.prev.status
     this.status.std
     "t" change.case$
   }
   if$
   "title" bibinfo.check
   duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
   { quote.close 'this.status.quote :=
     is.last.char.not.punct
       { punct.std 'this.status.punct := }
       { punct.no 'this.status.punct := }
     if$
     select.language
     bold 
     "``" swap$ *
     cap.status.std
   }
   if$
   } ```

   There may be other places where a similar modification is required, but at least this takes care of all article citations.