# One specific author bold with IEEEtran.bst bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieeetran, bold, ieee-style

I would like to put 1 specific author in bold in my bibliography.

- I need to use IEEEtran.bst bibliography style, but I couldn't find any example in the documentation (http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf).
- I cannot modify my .bib file since it is shared with other documents that do not require the bold author.

This post: [Bold of authors list changes style with bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53983/bold-of-authors-list-changes-style-with-bibtex)
was much more helpful than the IEEEtran documentation, however it puts in bold ALL authors, not one specific author.

(The solution here: [Make one author's name bold every time it shows up in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33330/make-one-authors-name-bold-every-time-it-shows-up-in-the-bibliography) doesn't work.)

I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved  by creating a copy of IEEEtran.bst and by using the tips in this post: [Why is the BST hack for highlighting author name not working?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361666/why-is-the-bst-hack-for-highlighting-author-name-not-working)

Hopefully it's helpful for someone :)