# Bold (or smallcaps) typesetting in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, typography

I'd like to generate a bibliography where authors (or maybe the title of the cited document) are printed in bold/small caps. However, I've just been able to find the following entry related with this topic

[Making bibtex reference entry bold?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/making-bibtex-reference-entry-bold)

where each entry in the bibliography needs to be tuned by hand. Unfortunately, I have such a long bibliography that I'd like to consider a cleaner/more automatic approach to do that. Is this possible? If so, how should I tune the small code below using pdflatex+bibtex?

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \title{This is my first document}
> \begin{document}
> \maketitle
> Hello~\cite{AmSLaTeX},~\cite{nothing}.
> \bibliography{biblio}
> \bibliographystyle{is-plain}
> \end{document}
> ```

with this bibliography

```
@ARTICLE{nothing,
         author    = "{noone et al.}",
         title     = "nothing",
         journal   = "nowhere",
         year      = 1986, }
@MANUAL{AmSLaTeX,
         author    = "{American Mathematical Society}",
         title     = "amslatex Version 1.2 User's Guide",
         month     = jan,
         year      = 1995, }
```

**Edit**

PS: This entry may be also useful to any forthcoming readers:
[Biblatex bibliography title fields for different entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191559/biblatex-bibliography-title-fields-for-different-entries)

Comment: Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178862) help? Can be easily adapted to small caps as well.

Comment: Check it out! http://nodonn.tipido.net/bibstyle.php It finds the `bibliographystyle` with the desired characteristics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set author's last name in small caps but avoid them for editors, translators, etc using biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29861/set-authors-last-name-in-small-caps-but-avoid-them-for-editors-translators-et).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have such a functionality easilly with the `biblatex` package, by redefining the `mkbibnamefamilly` command.
See also the p.95 of the biblatex (Version 2.8a 25/11/2013) documentation.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
@ARTICLE{nothing,
         author    = {Noone and others},
         title     = "nothing",
         journal   = "nowhere",
         year      = 1986, }
@MANUAL{AmSLaTeX,
         author    = {{American Mathematical Society}},
         title     = "amslatex Version 1.2 User's Guide",
         month     = jan,
         year      = 1995, }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblio}
% Chose one of the following.
\renewcommand\mkbibnamefamily[1]{\textbf{#1}}
%\renewcommand\mkbibnamefamily[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\begin{document}
Hello~\cite{AmSLaTeX},~\cite{nothing}.
\printbibliography[title={My Custom Title}]
\end{document}
```

(Versions prior to biblatex 3.3 should use `\mkbibnamelast` instead of `\mkbibnamefamily`.)

If you uncomment the "small caps" version and comment the bold version, you get :

[image: Sample output]

The general way to adopt `biblatex` is explained in the answer's to [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/34551).

**Edit**
You can finely tune what will be displayed in bold / small caps with the following options:

> `\mkbibnamefamily{text}` This command, which takes one argument, is used
>   to format the last name of all authors, editors, translators,
>   etc.
>   `\mkbibnamefirst{text}` Similar to `\mkbibnamefamily`, but
>   intended for the first name.
>  `\mkbibnameprefix{text}` Similar to
>   `\mkbibnamefamily`, but intended for the name prefix.
>   `\mkbibnameaffix{text}` Similar to `\mkbibnamefamily`, but intended for
>   the name affix.

Comment: Thank you very much. That biblatex seems really interesting. To typeset the title in bold, I've found that page 128 of http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf seems to put the title in emphasized mode, I'll try it tomorrow...

Comment: It should be `author={{American Mathematical Society}}`, as it's a single name. Probably the second one should be `author={noone and others}`

Comment: @egreg : thank you, I did not okked at the `bib` file at all, but you are right.

Comment: @redcrash : you can edit the title of the bibliography with the `title={My title}` option, I'l edit my answer in a minute.

Comment: I added \DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\textbf{#1}} in order to get the title of each entry of the bibliography in bold, but on the example given only the book was printed in bold, whereas the title of the article was printed as normal. Which is the appropriate field in article to typeset the title in bold?

Comment: And why no create your own style using the `custom-bib` package and the tool `makebst`, you run `latex makebst` solve the questions (one of them is about *author's font* and *title font*). This allows change several features of the bibliography format without touch the `.bib` file.

Comment: @redcrash : I would say that this is another question.

Answer (score -1):

You could open the .bib file and do a find and replace of `author = "  {` with `author =`"\textbf{`

This seems a bit of an annoying hack though.  I'm sure you could find a better way to do it in the .bst file.

Comment: This is not good since the closing brace `}` should be inserted one by one. The coudl should be `author = {\textbf{D.E. Knuth}},`

Comment: Biblatex provides such a functionlaity without hack, and OP made it clear that he had a "long bibliography" and would like a "more automatic approach". Editing the `bib` file by hands do not seems to be an option.

Comment: Yes, that's it as Clément states, but thank you for the comment dmt. BTW, what does OP mean? :)

Comment: @redcrash : [from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_post#Thread) : "Original post or original poster, the first post or person to post on a topic in an Internet forum"