# Seeking Assistance: Small Caps Issue in Bibliography Using BibLaTeX and XeLaTeX

Tags: small-caps

Firstly, I would like to apologize. It's customary to submit a Minimal Working Example (MWE), but my working file is so extensive that I'm unable to identify where the issue lies. Therefore, I'm writing to explain my current situation and ask for assistance.

Question: I encounter an issue when I include the bibliography. Specifically, I want to see a result like "BROWN (in small caps), John (in regular lowercase)". However, in the output, it shows as "BROWN (in small caps), JOHN (also in small caps)". If I use a font that doesn't support small caps, it entirely outputs as "Brown (in regular lowercase), John (in regular lowercase)".

Working Environment: I'm using TeXShop (version 5.12), Bibdesk (1.8.18 (6107)), biber, and XeLaTeX on MacOS Monterey Version 12.6.2.

My "tex" working file and the "bib" database file are well-connected. I've specified the path accurately to read the necessary data clearly.

In the bib file, the Author field is entered as {\textsc{Brown}, John}. Even if I remove the \textsc or change it to {John Brown}, the issue with small caps remains the same.

I am required to use Times New Roman in my document. However, I've heard that Times New Roman does not support small caps. So, I've tested with three fonts that resemble Times New Roman and support small caps (Latin Modern, TeX Gyre Termes, Nimbus Roman No9 L). The results were all the same. Contrary to my intention, it only outputs as "BROWN (in small caps), JOHN (also in small caps)".

Thank you for taking the time to read and consider my situation.

Comment: [Bold (or smallcaps) typesetting in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191401/106162) is probably the best way to set this up, check the log for any font warnings.

Comment: you shouldn't use \textsc in the bib-file. How the author is printed in the bibliography depends on the bibliography style you use, so you will have to create a minimal example that shows your setup.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} 

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{{\addfontfeatures{Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps}#1}}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=chicago-authordate,
  maxbibnames=3,
  maxcitenames=2,
  autocite=superscript,
  doi=true,
  url=true,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{{\textsc{\normalsize #1}}} 

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{smith2020,
  author = {Smith, John},
  title = {The Importance of Small Caps},
  journal = {Journal of Typography},
  year = {2020},
  volume = {10},
  number = {2},
  pages = {20-35},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

This is an example document showcasing the usage of small caps in LaTeX.

\smallcaps{Small caps} is a typographic feature that formats text in uppercase letters but with reduced size. It can be useful for emphasizing certain words or names, such as \smallcaps{Smith}.

\subsection{Citations}

Here is a citation example using the \texttt{biblatex-chicago} style. According to \textcite{smith2020}, small caps are important in typography.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: The result]

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I have managed to identify the issue and extract the most relevant part related to small caps. 
In this modified MWE, I've made the following changes:

Set the main font to "TeX Gyre Termes" since Times New Roman does not support small caps.
Defined the \smallcaps command to enable the use of small caps with proper sizing.
Included a bibliography entry for "Smith, John" to demonstrate the citation (without \textsc{...})
I hope this updated MWE accurately reflects your requirements.

Comment: why do you need the \smallcaps command? \textsc should work fine.